# ZF2 from any module redirect to module login

Tags: php, redirect, module, zend-framework2

I study ZF2 and have problem with login process. I have two modules login and moduleExample. 
Login module is based on http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/zend-framework-2-create-login-authentication-using-authenticationservice-with-rememberme/
I can redirect moduleExample to login route with condition hasIdentity() in Controllers, but can I set redirecting to this module at one place? Controllers will probably be more. I've already tried in onBootstrap method (Module.php), but then it is redirected everywhere (in all modules).

Where I can do what I describe?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to handle the login redirection at one place, one way is to define a custom event which is called in the routing event chain. To do this, you have to add the handler in your **Module.php** (preferably in the authentication module):

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
       $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
       $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
       $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
       $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
       //attach event here
       $eventManager->attach('route', array($this, 'checkUserAuth'), 2);
   }

   public function checkUserAuth(MvcEvent $e)
   {
       $router = $e->getRouter();
       $matchedRoute = $router->match($e->getRequest());

       //this is a whitelist for routes that are allowed without authentication
       //!!! Your authentication route must be whitelisted
       $allowedRoutesConfig = array(
          'auth'
       );
       if (!isset($matchedRoute) || in_array($matchedRoute->getMatchedRouteName(), $allowedRoutesConfig)) {
           // no auth check required
           return;
       }
       $seviceManager   = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
       $authenticationService = $seviceManager->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
       $identity = $authenticationService->getIdentity();
       if (! $identity) {
           //redirect to login route...
           $response = $e->getResponse();
           $response->setStatusCode(302);
           //this is the login screen redirection url
           $url = $e->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '/auth/login';
           $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
           $app = $e->getTarget();
           //dont do anything other - just finish here
           $app->getEventManager()->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, $e);
           $e->stopPropagation();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you tried is correct, so then you just need this little bit here

```
$controller = $e->getTarget();    
$params = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();

if(!$params['controller'] == 'your login conroller path e.g. RouteFolder/Controller/LoginControllerName'){

return $controller->redirect()->toRoute('your redirect route')
}
```

do a

> print_r($params['controller'])

and see what it returns and you will understand what i mean

so the event onBoostrap wont redirect you if your current location is the controller where the user comes to login